# Associate subterms to RefinableString

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, refiner, term-set

I have this taxonomy group below:

[image]

Now I have a `RefinableString` mapping the `Produto e Serviço` group term. Is it possible to map the `SubTema 1` term and the `Capítulo 1` term to a **different RefinableString**?

**Example**:

> - Tema 1 (first level) - `RefinableString01`,
> - SubTema 1 (second level) - `RefinableString02`,
> - Capitulo 1 (third level) - `RefinableString03`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you map the taxonomy group?

Per my knowledge, we can only map the crawled property to a managed property.

And we can only add term set to a managed metadata column, and might be crawled as crawled property.

Comment: I mapped the crawled property to a managed property that is associated with a term set. But I got this result: 

`RefinableString107` - *Tema 1:SubTema 1:Capitulo 1*

Comment: we cannot map different level of terms to different managed properties.